# What's Client's Public Key of HTTPS two-way authentication?

Tags: ssl, browser, https, public-key

When HTTPS performs two-way authentication,
The Server needs to obtain the Client's public key from the Client.

I have question about the Public Key:

The Client here is the browser, I want to know what's the Client's Public Key, does it refer to the Public Key of the Client's OS's? or is it mean a browser's ? if is browser's, how to check the Public Key of Chrome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The public key of the client in a HTTPS connection is the public key of the client certificate. This client certificate needs to be specifically imported into the browser (or need to be backed by a smart card etc). Thus it neither depends on the OS nor on the browser but instead on the specific user. Therefore client certificates in HTTPS are used to authenticate users, not the OS or the browser.

Comment: So, there always should install certificate import into browser, then the client have CA, right? Whether in HTTPS after we configurated the `private key` and `certificate` in webserver, the HTTPS is only one-way authentication? there should install private key and certificate into Browser, there then is two-way authentication?

Comment: @244boy: I'm not fully sure what you mean. But in general the client authenticates the server in order to make sure that it talks to the right server and not to some man in the middle. The server can request the client to authenticate itself too with a certificate, which then is called authentication by client certificate or mutual authentication or two-way authentication. To make this work the client must actually have a client certificate and matching private key installed in the browser which is acceptable to the server.